# How to retrieve and iterate over sound data chunks in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio, aiff

Given an audio file 'coolsound.aif', how might I approach the task of retrieving the sound data chunks (SSND chunks) and iterating over them to do some arbitrary processing? I hope to be able to achieve something like the following:

```
/*
* Pseudocode of what I'd like to do
*/

// get SSND chunks out of audio file somehow
Array soundDatachunks = getSSNDChunksFromSoundFile("coolsound.aif");

// iterate over each chunk
foreach(soundDataChunks as chunk){

  // Now iterate over each element in the waveForm data array
  foreach(chunk.waveForm as w){
      //Just log it to debug console for now
      Log(w);
  }
}
```

**Other info:**
- My aim is to use the waveform data to visualize the audio file graphically.
- The audio file was recorded using AudioToolbox [in this manner](http://trailsinthesand.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/audiorecorderappdelegate.m).
- SSND chunk has the structure as appears in this [source](http://muratnkonar.com/aiff/index.html):

```
typedef struct {
      ID             chunkID;
      long           chunkSize;
      unsigned long  offset;
      unsigned long  blockSize;
      unsigned char  WaveformData[];
    }  SoundDataChunk;
```

Comment: Checkout the documentation on [Audio Converter Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007943).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different API's that you can use and it all depends on how much control you want, and what you plan on doing with the audio data.  The ExtendedAudioFile API is made for basic operations like getting the audio data and drawing it.

It may seem like a lot of code to make this happen, like you have to create a AudioStreamBasicDescription object and configure it just right, but it allows you to read an entire audio file very quickly and access all the samples for drawing.

GW